# How to try-find element in an infinite ordered sequence?

Tags: f#, sequence

If I have an infinite sequence, I cannot use a normal `Seq.tryFind`.

However, if the sequence is ordered, that means the search could be cancelled when I detect that no other element in the sequence can ever satisfy my condition.

Is there an elegant way to express such a search?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another possible solution. It is quite similar to what @desco posted, but it is using sequence expressions instead of `Seq.tryPick` and it also does not need nested option types:

```
let has element input = 
  seq { for v in input do
          if v = element then yield Some v
          if v > element then yield None }
  |> Seq.head
```

Or even nicer and simpler solution using built-in functions. Just use `Seq.takeWhile` to take the beginning of the sequence containing only elements that are smaller or equal than the one you're looking for and then use `Seq.tryFind` on this part of the sequence:

```
let has element input = 
  input |> Seq.takeWhile (fun x -> x <= element)
        |> Seq.tryFind (fun x -> x = element)
```

Or if you fancy the point-free style (which I do not, because it gets harder to read IMHO):

```
let has element = Seq.takeWhile ((>=) element) >> Seq.tryFind ((=) element)
```

Comment: After asking the question i ended up finding the second method myself, but the first one is quite nice as well. Thanks!

Comment: `takeWhile` returns element one at a time?

Comment: Would it be even better if the sequence was traversed just once? `let has element = Seq.skipWhile ((>) element) >> Seq.take 1 >> Seq.tryFind ((=) element)`

Comment: @bytebuster: The sequence *is* only traversed once, almost everything in `Seq` is deferred until the elements are really needed (e.g. aggregation or iteration). `takeWhile` basically just adds a modfier to the generated sequence, docs: `Returns a sequence that, when iterated, yields elements of the underlying sequence while the given predicate returns true`

Answer (score 5):

if you want to use just standard functions - something like this will work

```
let evens =  Seq.initInfinite ((*)2)
let has v = 
    Seq.tryPick (fun x ->
        if x = v then Some (Some v)
        elif x > v then Some None
        else None)
    >> Option.bind id
has 40 evens // Some 40
has 41 evens // None
```